# Phonegap/cordova connect directly to MS SQL database (not through any Web)

Tags: javascript, android, asp.net, sql-server, cordova

I have a task to write an Bar-code reader. Which will connect directly to an MS SQL Server to find an product.

Basically, I can write a ASP.net website and write Javascript code to call it from Cordova (Android) app. Or write an native code and call it from Cordova.

But my task it "Directly connect" to Ms SQL server by using Javascript code. Does any way to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

Connecting *directly* to the database is not a very good idea. Instead, your database should be exposed by an **API**.

In your case, your best bet is to use the built in **ASP.NET WebAPI**. You can find more information about ASP.NET WebAPI [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api).

To call the WebAPI endpoints, you'll want to use HTTP, or HTTPS calls. [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) has quite a nice set of functions you can use.

You want to ensure that each layer of your application is separated. If you start putting SQL queries inside your mobile app, then this will spell disaster when it comes to any kind of debugging, or even refactoring.